# If and Do Until Loop EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

New to VBA if someone could help me what im doing wrong here.
Trying to run a loop such that it looks for a specific text, starts the loop then stops at a specific point. 
The loops is such that I want it to copy some values below in my sheet hence a is 55. 
Im facing the error Block IF without End If

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
For y = 1 To 15 Step 5
Dim x As Double
Dim a As Double
x = 1
a = 55
If Cells(x, y).Value = "Text1" Then
Do Until Cells(x, y).Value = "Text2"
Cells(a, y) = Cells(x, y).Value
Cells(a, y + 1) = Cells(x, y + 1)
x = x + 1
a = a + 1


Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: If you indent your code you'll find 2 errors: 1.  `If Cells(x, y).Value = "Text1" Then` without `End If`,  2. `For y = 1 To 15 Step 5` without `Next y`

Comment: If i was using if and then i thought i didnt need to use End if?

Comment: AFAIK the *only* time you don't need `End If` is if your `If` statement is on one line ...and even then, it's best practice to use a structred `If` statement.  For example, this doesn't need `End If`: `If myVal = 1 then Cells(1,1).Value = "Okay"`  all on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the issues I mentioned in the comments to your post, if I understood you correctly, you want to loop on cells at Column A, find the first "Text1", then copy all the cells to row 55 and below, until you find "Text2". If that's the case, try the code below :

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    For y = 1 To 15 Step 5

        x = 1  '<-- reset x and a (rows) inside the columns loop
        a = 55 '<-- start pasting from row 55

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row
        While x <= LastRow '<-- loop until last row with data in Column y
            If .Cells(x, y).Value Like "Text1" Then
                Do Until .Cells(x, y).Value = "Text2"
                    .Cells(a, y).Value = .Cells(x, y).Value
                    .Cells(a, y + 1).Value = .Cells(x, y + 1).Value
                    x = x + 1
                    a = a + 1
                Loop
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Wend
    Next y
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes Thankyou that worked!
How could i edit it to to check every fifth column? I added the following for loop but it didnt work.

For y = 1 To 15 Step 5

Comment: @IsraShaikh  you want to do the exact copy paste for every 5th column? Until column 15?

Comment: yes @ShaiRado
So first it runs it on column 1, then column 6 etc until column 15

Comment: @IsraShaikh test the edited code, should work like you wanted

Comment: It works Thanks! Could you explain each of the code lines please! beginner with VBA could really use a helping hand.

Comment: @IsraShaikh I have, look at the comments inside the code

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Sure

Answer (score 4):

Indenting is the way forward, you have a `for` statement with no `next` and an `if` with no `End If`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    For y = 1 To 15 Step 5
        Dim x As Double
        Dim a As Double
        x = 1
        a = 55
        If Cells(x, y).Value = "Text1" Then
            Do Until Cells(x, y).Value = "Text2"
                Cells(a, y) = Cells(x, y).Value
                Cells(a, y + 1) = Cells(x, y + 1)
                x = x + 1
                a = a + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next y
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks tom! 
For some reason im not getting any output though. 
What i want is for my code to start from the first column, go through it and find Text1, which if it does copy the values onward to cells (a,1) until it reaches a cell that has Text2 after which it stops. Am i missing something?

Comment: Should also move the Declarations prior to the For Loop.

Comment: Also,  x and a should be Long or Integer, not Double

Comment: @ShaiRado `Long`, not `Integer`. CPU is optimized for 32-bit integers... and there's *a lot more* than 32,767 rows on a worksheet ;-)

Comment: @ShaiRado  For some reason im not getting any output though. What i want is for my code to start from the first column, go through it and find Text1, which if it does copy the values onward to cells (a,1) until it reaches a cell that has Text2 after which it stops. Am i missing something?

Comment: @IsraShaikh **"from the first column, go through it and find Text1"** Your code is only going to check the first row for Text1. There is no increment for x (the row) before you find Text1. So if `Cells(1, 1) <> "Text1"` you are going to immediately go to the next iteration of the outer loop (y = 6).

Comment: @MarkBalhoff what changes could I make to MY code to implement that?

Comment: @IsraShaikh Exactly what the other answer did. Add a loop around the if statement that increments x (the row) until you either find Text1 or reach the end of the column.

Comment: Got it Thanks! @MarkBalhoff